# JSON Deletion Bug

Tags: python, json, indexing

I am iterating through a JSON file and deleting elements, if they have an index equal to a city code, which is in my case, route_code = 'LIM', it will be deleted. Here is my code without deleting anything:

```
x = -1
for j in data['routes']:
    x += 1
    if(j['ports'][0] == route_code) or (j['ports'][1] == route_code):
        print("inside of loop")
        print(data['routes'][x])
        print(x)
```

This is the return value before I delete the elements:

```
inside of loop
{'distance': 2453, 'ports': ['SCL', 'LIM']}
0
inside of loop
{'distance': 4231, 'ports': ['LIM', 'MEX']}
1
inside of loop
{'distance': 1879, 'ports': ['LIM', 'BOG']}
2
Left for loop
[{'distance': 2453, 'ports': ['SCL', 'LIM']}, {'distance': 4231, 'ports':           ['LIM', 'MEX']}, {'distance': 1879, 'ports':
```

Now, Here's my code for when I delete the elements, I just added one line at bottom:

```
x = -1
for j in data['routes']:
    x += 1
    if(j['ports'][0] == route_code) or (j['ports'][1] == route_code):
        print("inside of loop")
        print(data['routes'][x])
        print(x)
        del data['routes'][x]
```

Now, here is my return value:

```
inside of loop
{'distance': 2453, 'ports': ['SCL', 'LIM']}
0
inside of loop
{'distance': 1879, 'ports': ['LIM', 'BOG']}
1
Left for loop
[{'distance': 4231, 'ports': ['LIM', 'MEX']}, {'distance': 2499, 'ports':     ['MEX', 'LAX']}, {'distance': 2714,
```

As you can see, by adding the delete statement, the if statement was only reached 2 times instead of 3. Therefore, the index that contains ['Lim', 'Mex'] is not deleted. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data['routes'] = [
    item for item in data['routes'] if route_code not in item['ports']
]
```

Note also that if you absolutely want to loop through a list and its index, you can use

```
for index, item = enumerate(data['routes']):
    ...
```

... but you don't even need the index. Where it says `print(data['routes'][x])` you could have said `print(j)`. The problem you're having is deleting from a list while looping through is, which is hazardous.